# How to position outer div acting as master container for 960 grid system

Tags: css

I am using a 12 column 960 px grid system for a site. My client wants to accept advertisements to both sides of the site as can be seen from the screenshot I took from another site.

**Problem 1:**
I thought of having an external div host the container_12 div. In that case I could have given it a background image via css and have that image within an anchor tag to redirect the user to the advertisement owner's page when clicked on it.

this is my code:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; min-height:100%; position:fixed; z-index:999; overflow:auto; background-image:url('img/960.png');"></div>
    <div class="container_12" style="z-index:1;">
        <div class="grid_12 rowAdd bgE">
            <div class="txtA" style="line-height:25px;">ADD ROW</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which produces the outcome in picture 1. The container_12 is not centered and the contents of it are not clickable at all.

**Problem 2:**

My client also wants to have adjacent divs both at right and left to host some other ads. Divs should be 220 pixels wide. He also wants the divs either be 'fixed' or 'absolutely positioned'. I am lost as I couldn't have the first problem solved yet. I would appreciate your help.

Picture 1:
[image]

Comment: I think a JSFiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Sidebars**

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/HxJiF)

Basic HTML

```
<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Basic CSS (width some colors for visual reference)

```
.container {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #c0ffee;
  height:600px;
}

.left, .right {
  position:absolute;
  height:600px;
  width:220px;
  top:0;
}

.left {
  right:50%;
  margin-right:480px;
  background-color: grey;

}

.right {
 left:50%;
 margin-left:480px;
 background-color: red;  
}
```

Comment: hey Paulie thank you for the answer. I tried your codepen demo but when i have long content within the container div, the div does not grow. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Yep. The Codepen has now been updated. I removed the height from the sidebars and added `bottom:0` to the position settings and they are now always full height.

Comment: Yes, this seems to solve the second problem. Do you have any ideas about the first one? Doesn't have to be code any ideas to direct me to a correct way would do..

Comment: You can wrap another div around the 'container' if you want but I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with it. Why does it have to be 'fixed' like in your code?

Comment: The clients wants to have an ad like the one at www.takvim.com.tr like a background image. And i am not sure how to achieve that kind of a structure while i am stuck with 960 grid system and cannot have the main container (which you style by using the container_12 class sit correctly within another div

Comment: Wny can't the main container sit inside another div? There's nothing in the 960gs to stop you.